# Run a script between compiling and linking

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode-project

I'm looking for a way to add an auto-generated code to an app, and the code is dependent on the compiled object files.

Is there a way to run a script after the source files were compiled, but before the object files are linked?

Adding a build phase between "Compile sources" and "Link Binary With Library" doesn't help, since it turns out that the linking actually happens as a part of the "Compile sources" phase. Is there any way to separate the phases?

(I guess it's possible to use additional target to achieve this, but I have to do it inside the target, without creating additional targets.)